# MS Access freezing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

My Microsoft Access 2007 is freezing on me. Could it be the 700 queries?

Yes, it's on a network, but only 2-3 people are accessing the backend at a time.

I have tried compact and repair, and also yelling at it. Nothing worked.

Comment: How is the application used?  Are there forms with chatty communication to the database?  When specifically does it tend to freeze?  Is your network efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I can assure you that up to 15 persons working simultenously with back-end MDB should be fine with no visible freezing.

You can explore the following:

1. How big is your MDB? if it is too big consider splitting it to smaller parts and put all your historical and rarely accessed data into the separate file -- you can easily re-bind all the table in front-end to multiple back-end files.
2. Check your queries and VBA code. Use optimistic locks everywhere you can and avoid locking tables for reading purposes!
3. Check your network connectivity and hard drive throughput? Is your serving trying to perform a virus scan every time you update your MDB? Maybe an update is running?
4. If nothing helps -- try to install MS SQL Express, quickly upsize your tables and re-bind those to your front-end using ODBC connection -- you won't need to re-write your queries (as long as those are written in agnostic SQL, without DISTINCTROW etc).

Comment: None of this helped my particular situation, but I do think these suggestions could help others who are experiencing similar problems. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a locking issue. The Jet engine was not designed for multi-user access, and does not handle it very well at all. You should consider upgrading to SQL Server, which handles it much better. The Express version of SQL Server is free, and MS Access has an upsizing wizard that will do all the hard work for you.